# how to fix override state in android

Tags: android, jdbc

i have activity and want to connect it through JDBC the connection is working fine but when i click the ok button as previous connection discard and app crash but when i click ok button with wrong values and toast show message for correct values then that connection string runs and activity would be in override state.
i just want to get the solution that how can i fix that override issue as i can get the result and call the function without calling the connection string again and again because it takes time to connect and when click on button without input mistake app crash.
here is the code:

i want that the connection string works without clicking the button and no affect of override. please help

dbcon=DBConnection.instance(this);

```
    final TextView voternumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    final EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.vnumberedit);
    final ImageView vok=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.vnumberok);

    dbcon.connect("ip:1433", "pass", "login", "db");

    vok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dbcon.connect("ip:1433", "pass", "login", "db");

            final String st=ed.getText().toString();
            int len=st.length();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(st)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Provide Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                String id=dbcon.GetID(st,);
                txt.setText(id);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you post your logcat output?

Comment: when app crash it shows fatal exception error main

Comment: it is not work until i press ok button

Comment: i want to get rid of override in this situation which clear the previous values